# How can I make a ggplot2 scatter plot using lubridate hours in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, lubridate

I have a set of hours (some greater than 24) that represents the time some students spent on studying sessions. I want to make a scatter plot of studying time and exam results using ggplot2. The thing is the total time data is in lubridate's time format, how do I plot using this? Example:

```
            Name          ID           Total Time  Results
1         Student1      xx-xxxxx-xx    9H 56M 0S   37.58
2         Student2      xx-xxxxx-xx   10H 28M 0S   73.89
3         Student3      xx-xxxxx-xx    6H 40M 0S    4.14
4         Student4      xx-xxxxx-xx    3H 22M 0S   33.44
```

Comment: Post example of your data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `lubridate` `Total Time` column is represented as a period which cannot be plotted directly in something like ggplot. Fortunately, it's very easy to convert a lubridate period into numeric object at whatever level you wish (i.e. hour, minutes, seconds).

After that, it's very easy to plot with your numeric time dimension as your x axis and your results as your y axis.

Here's an example with your data:

```
library(lubridate)

# Replicate your data
example <- data.frame(Name = c("Student1","Student2","Student3","Student4"),
            TotalTime = hms(c("09H 56M 0 S","10H 28M 0S","06H 40M 0S", "03H 22M 0S")),
            Results = c(37.58,73.59,4.14,33.44))

example$TotalTime <- as.numeric(example$TotalTime, "hours")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(example, aes(TotalTime, Results)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: How can I make the time scale look like yours? Mine looks like decimals.

Comment: The methods for `as.numeric` aren't documented that I can find. I consider myself to be well-versed in `lubridate`, but it was new to me that you could use an `"hours"` argument like that. Do you know where you found that?

Comment: I saw it in an [issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/lubridate/issues/420) discussing this approach on the lubridate github project page.

Comment: The code to create the sample data frame appears to no longer work. I tried creating the vectors separately. The error seems to be in running the code to create the TotalTime variable. It brings up the error message "Error: All arguments must be numeric or NA." Any idea what might need to be changed?